# Assigning different directory permission for each different groups

Tags: permissions, directory, chmod, chown

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit server on ext4.

There are four user groups - `marketing`, `sales`, `admin` and `etc`.

I need to assign different permissions to `/archive` as follows:

`rw` for the `marketing` group
`r` for the `sales` group
`rwx` for the `admin` group
`w` for the `etc` user group

How exactly can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following command :

Use Access Lists :

```
sudo apt-get install acl
```

1) Add the option acl to the partition(s) on which you want to enable ACL in `/etc/fstab`. For example:

```
 ...  
 UUID=07aebd28-24e3-cf19-e37d-1af9a23a45d4    /home    ext4   defaults,acl   0   2  
 ...
```

2) If necessary, remount partition(s) on which ACLs were enabled for them to take effect. For example:

```
sudo mount -o remount /home
```

3) Verify that ACLs are enabled on the partition(s):

```
mount | grep acl
```

4) Add a group to acl

The utility setfacl is used to add the groups blue and green to the ACL for the directory `/var/www`.

```
sudo setfacl -m g:green:rwx /var/www/  
sudo setfacl -m g:blue:rwx /var/www/  
sudo getfacl /var/www/  
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names  
file: var/www/  
owner: root  
group: root  
user::rwx  
group::r-x  
group:green:rwx  
group:blue:rwx  
mask::rwx  
other::r-x
```